# end="" and time.sleep() relation

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```
import random
import time
myStr="1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm.,*/-+>£#$½{[]}\|!'^+%&/()=?_é><`;:"

def generator():
while True:
    randomLetter=random.choice(myStr)
    print(randomLetter,end="")
    time.sleep(0.1)

generator()
```

I want to slow down my while loop . If i write time.sleep it doesnt output anything .If i delete end="" part it works but i still want to write everything in one line and I also tried with "sys.stdout.write" but it didnt work again.

Answer (score 0):

do `sys.stdout.flush()` after `print`

Comment: you are perfect man